# MUI Datatable not registrering options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mui-datatable

I am trying to set options for the MUI-Datatable (https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables) component. However, when trying to provide options it doesn't seem to registre the option I provide from my options object.
Currently, my code looks as follows:

```
const statements = [
      {
        date: moment().format('MM/DD'),
        details: 'Hello Chris, this is a wide details :)',
        deposit: 0,
        withdraw: 200,
        balance: 300,        
      },
      {
        date: moment().format('MM/DD'),
        details: '24/7 purchase',
        deposit: 0,
        withdraw: 200,
        balance: 100,        
      }
]

const columns = ['Date', 'Details', 'Paid in ($)', 'Paid out ($)', 'Balance ($)'];
  
  const options = {
    page: 9,
    pagination: false,
  };
  
  statements.map((statement) => {
    statement.deposit = (statement.deposit === 0) ? statement.deposit == null : statement.deposit;
    statement.withdraw = (statement.withdraw === 0) ? statement.withdraw == null : statement.withdraw;

    data.push(Object.values(statement));
  });

return (
    <MUIDataTable className={dataTable} data={data} columns={columns} option={options} />
);
```

However, the table still displays the pagination and 10 rows per page. Any clue why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I'm stupid, were missing an "s" in the options property on the component..